# browse-url default to certain url

Tags: url, web-browser, w3m

Whenever I use browse-url function inside of w3m I would like to have
a default URL displayed for me.

It happens that what I mostly do is google searches, so if I could
have https://google.com/search?q= as default URL any time I use
browse-url it would save me a lot of typing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of what I have in my init file, just customize it a little bit and you're ready to go

```
(defun duckduckgo (what)
  "Use ddg to search for WHAT."
  (interactive "sSearch: ")
  (browse-url-firefox (concat "https://duckduckgo.com/?t=lm&q="
                              (url-unhex-string what))))
```